# When to use double size images

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was thinking to write some quiz app where questions are represented as images.

My question is, for each quiz question (`question.jpg`), and thus a jpg file, do I have to create
a double sized `question@2x.jpg` file?

*Is it necessary?*

Doing this seems will increase size of my program so I was thinking when/if this is necessary to do?

PS. And in case I have to do it, I will just have to double in size each image manually and add to the project right (both original and double sized image)?

PPS. Just to add more info. The questions are located on the web site, I have to download them and add to my project manually (like resources). On web site there are no different versions of the same image. So, I have whatever is on the web site. Some images I noticed are 800x600 in dimensions but some are also in dimentions 500x400. So after I download these images, how shall I name them? Just with original names? and forget about the `@2x` extension? What's the best practice?
(if this will help my *image view* will probably be smth .like 310 in width). Do I have to modify them in size? What to do?

Comment: Actually it is NOT necessary. The `@2x` images are there for you to provide better quality images for the retina display devices. If you just enlarge your image, you don't get the quality you could. Why don't you create the `@2x` images first (using your originals) and then shrink them for the .jpg? Let me also say that I have tried including ONLY `@2x` images and still everything works ok for older devices.

Comment: @gWiz: I need to download the JPG images from a web site. I just downloaded one, it says dimensions are 800x600. So, what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: download big images and then shrink them programmatically?

Comment: @cekisakurek: can you be more specific? Why programatically? Like I said each image seems to be a 800x600 JPG. So, which version should I use as original, and which one should be `@2x` version? and do I need to include both versions of the images?

Comment: @2x is a naming convention for static image resources. For dynamic image resources it won't work. Lets say you have an image view size of 400x300. First think is check if the device has retina display. if it has retina display, you should download 800x600. if there is no retina display. you should look for 400x300 image. Note that you still can display 800x600(shrinking the image to half) image in old devices but it has performance impacts and unnecessary bandwidth usage.

Comment: @cekisakurek: I found your answer a bit confusing. These are static resources. My `image view` probably will be smth like 310 in width, height not sure. The images are on the web site, there are no different versions of the images on the web site, whatever dimension there is, I need to use that one. Like I said some of the images are in dimensions 800x600 but I've noticed some have smaller dimensions, maybe like 500x400. So, how to do this image management in my app? Shall I just download these images the way they are, add to my project, and forget about `@2x` extension?

Comment: For static images I meant images embedded to the project. not downloaded from a source. Yes you should download the images the way they are because @2x convention is only apply to the local sources.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's naming conventions of high resolution images can be found here:
[Apple doc naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html)

If you are developing in the way that you want to support old screen as well as retina screens. You can use xxxx.jpg for old devices as iPhone 3gs and iPad 1, and use xxxx@2x.jpg for retina displays. Where the aspect ratio needs to be the same but the @2x image needs to be twice as big.
In your case "my image view will probably be smth .like 310 in width", then the @2x image needs to be 620px in width and normal revolution 310px.

There is actually no need to have both image sizes in the app as you can use the same image and just scale it(If you really really need to have the old resolution supported).
Even if you add just a @2x, it will scale itself if someone on an old device installs your app. It may become a bit blurry but will still be quite ok.

If you are planning to use a lot of images in your app I suggest using some sort of web service where the user can download content that is to be shown. But that's just me. As the app will quite quickly become very large as images takes up quite a bit of space. Of course this all comes down to how many images you will have.
The drawback of using a web service is that the user much have an internet connection to be able to play. And download your content.(Most quiz apps I know of does use a web service for this.) This is a matter of taste.

If you do need to support normal and @2x here us a method you can use. This method will return the scaled image so you just need the normal one or the @2x one and then scale to the other size. This will at least help you a bit when it comes to getting either your app size down or your clients download time down.

If you are using .jpg's and scaling them upwards you can quite easily get a pixalated image as it is a lossy format. But if that's what you still want to do and maintain aspect ratio, this is one way to do it:

```
-(UIImage*)resizeImage: (UIImage *)imageToScale withScale:(CGFloat)theScale{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageToScale CGImage]
                                         scale:(imageToScale.scale * theScale)
                                   orientation:(imageToScale.imageOrientation)];
    return image;
}
```

Usage

```
    [self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"question.jpg"] withScale:0.5];
```

0.5 would double the size and 2.0 results in an image half the size as the original.

If you want a more complex method to set for instance set a specific target size just say so and I'll edit this answer.

Comment: I am not scaling anything yet, please look at the question more carefully. I suppose these things - which you suggest I can also do using some software - in case there is a need.

Comment: Oh, yes of course you can use software to resize the images server side. This solution is the no hassle version. As you can save them on the server in the size you are currently using and then scale them as soon as they are on the device. Saving you some bandwidth in the transfer of the data as you will only need to get the image at half the size. And as soon as it gets to the device you can scale it up so it looks better proportionately. I thought this was what you where after?

Comment: And what I was further offering to help you with is a method that you can get the image at whatever size you want and scale it to a target size of your choosing.

Comment: This is confusing. There are just some images on some web site. Image1.jpg, Image2.jpg, Image3.jpg, etc. I need to download them and add to the project as resources. Question: shall I use these images directly and forget about @2x extension?

Comment: Ok, well for one: are the images yours? Are you allowed to use them? I was taking for granted you had a running web service where you got your questions from and the images as well.
If the resource you are getting things from is subject to change, for instance images will change or questions will change, I would say that he best approach is to download and show. If you choose to put all images in your app you will get bloated pretty fast and it will become very hard to update questions and graphics.
Check connection, get question + image, resize do whatever to image, display and check.

Comment: they'll change very rarely I believe. Not sure about downloading, I don't have direct links, there are just pages, where many jpegs are embedded ...

Comment: Editing my above post to answer all your questions. And elaborate into different solutions.

Comment: I'll probably just use the images "as" they are